# Adding a .xlsx file to Pycharm on a chromebook

Tags: python, excel, pycharm, google-chrome-os

I've got Pycharm installed on my chromebook by enabling linux apps. I've started to learn Python using a tutorial by 'Programming by Mosh'. In one of the projects that he does in the tutorial, he adds an .xlsx file to a project in Pycharm. Mosh (he uses a Mac) did this by right clicking on project and then clicking 'Reveal in Finder' and then pasting the file onto the window that opens. Could you explain how I can do this on my chromebook, because I can't seem to find the 'Reveal in Finder' option.

Answer (score 0):

Both the operating systems are quite different. If you want to create an Excel file(.xlsx is used by Microsoft Excel), you can use Office Online and then download it to your project directory in Chromebook.

I would actually prefer you to use Google sheets instead if you're using Chrome OS.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the dropdown menu of  'Project' at the top and then click 'Project files'. Then just paste your file into it.